# Npgsql and NOT IN or !=ANY Queries

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

It seems that there is not standard support for the `IN` clause in `Npgsql`. I see posts that recommend using `= ANY` instead of `IN`.  This works great as a replacement for a standard `IN` clause.  However, Postgres (pgsql) does not seem to have anything that allows you to do a `NOT ANY` or `!=ANY` query. It does, however, support `NOT IN`, but it seems that `Npgsql` does not. Can someone help me understand how I might write an `Npgsql` compatible query like this one:

```
select * my_table where id NOT IN(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: is like this or are you using a select statement inside in() clause?

Comment: BTW the opposite to `=any()` is `!=all()`.

Answer (score 2):

First, this has nothing to do with Npgsql - it's a PostgreSQL question.

Second, PostgreSQL does have full standard support for `IN` clauses. It's important to understand the difference between `IN` and `ANY`: `IN` operates on *rows*, whereas `ANY` operates on *arrays* - the two definitely aren't the same, even though you can convert one into the other (e.g. see `unnest`). [Read the docs carefully](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html).

Finally, to answer your question... Saying `WHERE x != ANY(some_array)` means "where there's some element of some_array that isn't equal to x". This indeed isn't the same as what you want, which is "where none of some_array's elements are equal to x". You can achieve the latter with `WHERE x != ALL(some_array)`: this checks x against each and every element, returning true only if all of them are unequal.

You can also use `ANY` with simple logical negation: `WHERE NOT (x = ANY(SOME_ARRAY))`.

Comment: "_It's important to understand the difference between IN and ANY_" - try for example `explain verbose select 1 in (1,2,3);` Spoiler: `Output: (1 = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[]))`

Comment: That's interesting... Although I wonder if it's a special case for array *literals* (i.e. whether IN would be internally translated to ANY in other scenarios).

Comment: It is only for `in (list_of_constants_or_variables)` as I know. For `in (subquery)` scenario is different.